# Is there such a thing as a 64-bit .dll for the YAJSW Java service wrapper?

Tags: java, service, wrapper

Is there such a thing as a 64-bit .dll for the YAJSW Java service wrapper?  If so, where do I find it?   I know that the Tanuki JSW provides .dll files that go with the .jar files it distributes.   So, I am basically wondering if YAJSW has overcome this limitation and I dont need a .dll  OR  if I need to download one from somewhere?

The [YAJSW website](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/YAJSW%20Configuration%20Parameters.html) mentions the existence of a w86.dll file but provides no information on where to find it or whether you need it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding that reference to "w86.dll".  I think it is supposed to be an example of some 3rd party application specific DLL.  The text is about how to configure YAJSW to deal with such things.

I've never tried to use YAJSW, but the indications from the documentation is that 64 bit is supported for Windows.  It should "just work" if you follow the generic instructions.  Have you tried that?

Comment: I just found that on this page ( http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/YAJSW%20Configuration%20Parameters.html ) it says "wrapper.native_library" is "not necessary with YAJSW".  Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of supported platforms for YAJSW [here](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/#mozTocId768274).

YAJSW distribution comes with what you need to get it running so as long as you are on a supported platform you should be good to go.